# Return a value from a marker in a Leaflet Map to Django

Tags: python, django, leaflet

I want to choose an object for further data analysis by clicking on a Leaflet map marker. So, by clicking on a button on the information popup on the leaflet map, a API is called that sets the values for the following actions. I have the following questions:

1. How do I build that interactive popup that allows communication between the map and the database?
2. How do I construct this communication? AJAX?